Parented objects don't show as parented in the scene tree
In my scene, I have several parented objects.
They work correctly when I rotate or move them, but they don't show as parented in the scene tree.
You can see here that the hierarchy is working:
https://youtu.be/h4rwaDBIWH0
You can see here that deleting the collections solves the problem, which is not the expected behavior:
https://youtu.be/4yc_ZUf5sRk

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

I don't see how to add a GIF: adding an image doesn't show GIF as an option, so I opted for videos.

Try dragging and dropping your Gif into the edit field.

I would check and see if that object got put into the hidden BOOL collection by chance. If an object has a Parent-Child relationship it will still try to show it in the outliner but it will only show that specific one. If it's in a hidden collection then you might not see it.
